# Why cant different access modifiers be specified for automatically implemented property in C#

Tags: c#

Why is the below expression invalid? **I know how to resolve the errors but wondering the rationale behind now allowing this statement.**

```
public int Number {public get;protected set; }
```

I dont have a use case or application to elaborate on why this should be allowed. But the compiler throws 2 errors:

```
Error   2   The accessibility modifier of the 'LambdaExpressions.Program.Person.Number.get' accessor must be more restrictive than the property or indexer 'LambdaExpressions.Program.Person.Number'    LambdaExpressions\LambdaExpressions\Program.cs  66  39  LambdaExpressions
```

and

```
Error   1   Cannot specify accessibility modifiers for both accessors of the property or indexer 'LambdaExpressions.Program.Person.Number'  LambdaExpressions\LambdaExpressions\Program.cs  66  24  LambdaExpressions
```

Comment: It's just an error in your syntax, you can indeed do this; redefine your property as `public int Number { get;protected set; }` if you want `public` get and `protected` set.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because you already got to specify one of the modifiers first:

```
public int Number {public get;protected set; }
//^
//here
```

What would that modifier be modifying if you have modifiers on both accessors?

I.e. imagine an even odder example:

```
public int Number {protected get;protected set; }
```

Exactly *what* part or concept of `Number` is now `public`?

Per @dash's comments, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75e8y5dd.aspx):

> By default these accessors have the same visibility, or access level: that of the property or indexer to which they belong
>
> You can use accessor modifiers only if the property or indexer has both set and get accessors. In this case, the modifier is permitted **on one only of the two accessors**.

(**My emphasis**)

Comment: + 1 but I think it's worth mentioning that, although your example makes sense, the reason is actually because the spec says you only get to override the accessor on one of the properties - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75e8y5dd.aspx

Comment: I might add that quote, if you don't mind, but I think my answer addresses the rationale *behind* the spec.

Answer (score 6):

Because providing access modifier to a property not only delegates it automatically to `get` and `set`, but also *implies a restriction* that: even if any modifier applied on them has to be *more* restrictive that that one defined on the property itself.

Having this in mind, you *can* do

```
public int A {
    get; 
    private set; 
}
```

but you can not do (by design of the language)

```
    //both modifer can not have be more restrictive then property itself
    //non sence
    public int A {
        protected get; 
        private set; 
    }
```

yo can not do

```
    //one of modifiers is less restrictive
    //again non sence
    protected int A {
        public get; 
        set; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is redundant.  The access modifier is already public, specifying it again is pointless.

However, the real problem is that the C# language only allows you to specify more restrictive modifiers, thus the following code is illegal:

```
private int Number {public get; set;}
```

This has the side effect of also being illegal if you specify the same level (ie public and public).  It must be more restrictive.

You can also only specify one modifier, because it's pointless to place a access modifier on the property itself otherwise.

```
public int Number {protected get; private set;} // How is it public?
```